# Hive unix_timestamp function calculation mismatch

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am trying to write a Hive query which will add 6 hours to a timestamp value and then compare it with other timestamps.

The method I used is to convert the timestamp using the `unix_timestamp()` function and then add 21600 seconds to it so that final value is 6 hours ahead of the initial one.

```
hive> select unix_timestamp('2014-11-02 00:58:20') from unix_tmp limit 1;
OK
1414907900
```

1414907900 + 6*60*60 = 1414929500

```
hive> select from_unixtime(1414929500) from unix_tmp limit 1;
OK
2014-11-02 05:58:20
```

I think the hour value should be `06` and not `05`.  What am I doing wrong?

Also, another observation is that this is not true for all values; for some values the above calculation gives the correct result.

Is there a better method to do hour addition and timestamp comparison?

Comment: it is basically a problem with the GMT..Time Zone where Time Relative to GTM is +1 or more

Answer (score 2):

As the [docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) says:

`unix_timestamp(string date)`

> Converts time string in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss to Unix timestamp (in seconds), using the **default timezone** and the default locale, return 0 if fail:

`from_unixtime(bigint unixtime[, string format])`

> Converts the number of seconds from unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) to a string representing the timestamp of that moment in the **current system time zone** in the format of "1970-01-01 00:00:00".

---

**solution**

`from_utc_timestamp(timestamp, string timezone)`

> Assumes given timestamp is UTC and converts to given timezone (as of Hive 0.8.0). For example, from_utc_timestamp('1970-01-01 08:00:00','PST') returns 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

`to_utc_timestamp(timestamp, string timezone)`

> Assumes given timestamp is in given timezone and converts to UTC (as of Hive 0.8.0). For example, to_utc_timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00','PST') returns 1970-01-01 08:00:00.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I want to check whether TimeStamp1 > (TimeStamp2 + 6hrs) How can i do that

Comment: If you want to compare time_stamp, just covert the two time_stamp to `unix_timestamp` using `unix_timestamp()` function.

Comment: You are not adding hour to timestamp. Add hour to `unix_timestamp` which is bigint.

Comment: Thats what I was trying in the first place; it didnt worked out :-(

Comment: Comparing `unix_timestamp` result is fine. Your problem is coverting the `unix_timestamp` result back to `time_stamp string`. You could use `to_utc_timestamp` to make the time_stamp on the same base.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89362/discussion-between-anup-and-luoluo).